# adding progressBar for web service data android

Tags: android, progressdialog

I have a web service and I am getting data from webservice so ı have waiting time.To solve waiting , I prefer add progress dialog.When I added the progress bar , the project didnt work.Here is my codes :

```
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            setInfo();
        }

    };
    //Toast.makeText(CardChooseActivity.this, adapter.getItem(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    (new Thread(runnable)).start();
}
```

I call the setInfo function and here is my setInfo function:

```
    private void setInfo()
{
    final ProgressDialog ringProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(ReportAllActivity.this, "Please wait ...", "Downloading Infos...", true);
    ringProgressDialog.setCancelable(true); 
      new Thread(new Runnable() {
          @Override
          public void run() {
              try {
                    String successMessage="";
                    jsonObject = new JSONObject();

                    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(URL);
                    HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
                    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams,10000);
                    HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParams,10000);
                    try {
                        jsonObject.put("data", "data1");
                        jsonObject.put("data1", "data2");
                        jsonObject.put("data2", "data3");
                        jsonObject.put("data3", "data4");

                        StringEntity stringEntity = new StringEntity(jsonObject.toString());
                        stringEntity.setContentEncoding(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json"));
                        httpPost.setEntity(stringEntity);

                        CookieStore cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();
                        cookieStore.addCookie(cookie);
                        HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
                        localContext.setAttribute(ClientContext.COOKIE_STORE, cookieStore);
                        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost,localContext);
                        HttpEntity entity = httpResponse.getEntity();


                        if (entity != null) {
                            successMessage = EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity());
                            Log.i("Report All activity", successMessage);
                        }
                       jArray = new JSONArray(successMessage);

                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                    public void run() {

                                            fillTable(jArray);

                                    }
                               });


                    }catch (IOException e){
                        Log.e("Login_Issue", e.toString());
                    }catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();  
                    }
              } catch (Exception e) {

              }
              ringProgressDialog.dismiss();
          }
      }).start();
```

And my logcat errors:

```
09-07 10:37:17.156: E/AndroidRuntime(510): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-13
09-07 10:37:17.156: E/AndroidRuntime(510): java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler     
inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
09-07 10:37:17.156: E/AndroidRuntime(510):  at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:121)
09-07 10:37:17.156: E/AndroidRuntime(510):  at android.app.Dialog.<init>(Dialog.java:101)
09-07 10:37:17.156: E/AndroidRuntime(510):  at android.app.AlertDialog.<init>  
(AlertDialog.java:63)
09-07 10:37:17.156: E/AndroidRuntime(510):  at android.app.ProgressDialog.<init>  
(ProgressDialog.java:80)
09-07 10:37:17.156: E/AndroidRuntime(510):  at android.app.ProgressDialog.<init>       
(ProgressDialog.java:76)
09-07 10:37:17.156: E/AndroidRuntime(510):  at   
android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:101)
09-07 10:37:17.156: E/AndroidRuntime(510):  at     
android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:90)
09-07 10:37:17.156: E/AndroidRuntime(510):  at  
com.example.example.ReportAllActivity.setInfo(ReportAllActivity.java:119)
09-07 10:37:17.156: E/AndroidRuntime(510):  at           
com.example.example.ReportAllActivity.access$0(ReportAllActivity.java:117)
09-07 10:37:17.156: E/AndroidRuntime(510):  at          
com.example.example.ReportAllActivity$1.run(ReportAllActivity.java:109)
09-07 10:37:17.156: E/AndroidRuntime(510):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android basically works on two thread types namely UI thread and background thread. According to android documentation -

**Do not access the Android UI toolkit from outside the UI thread to fix this problem, Android offers several ways to access the UI thread from other threads.**

```
 private void setInfo()
{
     myactivity.this.runOnUiThread(new runnable()
            {
                public void run()
                {
                     final ProgressDialog ringProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(ReportAllActivity.this, "Please wait ...", "Downloading Infos...", true);
    ringProgressDialog.setCancelable(true); 
                }
            });

/// Your other code goes here...

}
```

Comment: it is help you then upvote it  and accept it then it also help other person.. thanks